# QFOTA always downloading always 0%

Tags: installation

I saw the question about the qfota download update package is always loading but never is complete. I have turned my tablet off and back on. No help.  Called Verizon customer service and they had me do a factory reset. It is still trying to download but always on "0%"....... Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Q fota,always downloading.
It is over the air,turn off WiFi
Then you will see it downloading,
Then you can turn WiFi back on.

Answer (score -1):

Keep letting it update. Eventually it finishes. No help from Verizon and so I had no choice but to let it run. Took about 6 weeks.